# How can I exclude results from a search query that has a specific request value?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to count the number of times a document with a specific field value is accessed per day for. I am doing this by retrieving the index for each day and then performing a search against each index.

**Search Query:**

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "field_to_find"
      },
    },
  }
}
```

**Document Result Structure:**

```
{  
  ...
  "_shards":{  
    ...
  },
  "hits": {  
    "total": 6,
    "hits": [{  
      ...
      "_source": {  
        "request": "/data/000000/comment",
        "field_to_find": 000000,
        ...
      }
    }, {  
      ...
      "_source": {  
        "request": "/data/111111",
        "field_to_find": 111111,
        ...
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to only count the hits that contain the request structure `/dataset/<data_id>`. I need to exclude all other values in the count.

What is the best most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Should `hits` array exclude `request` not like `/dataset/<data_id>`?

Comment: Exactly. How can I achieve this as I would need a wildcard or something like that as the second value is dynamic. E.g. exclude '/data/*/comment'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regexp Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "exists": {
          "field": "field_to_find"
        },
        "regexp": {
          "request": "^/data/[0-9]+$"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if your data is very large and the field `request` has a big cardinal. You can add a redundancy field which just used to indicate if your `request` matches the regex when indexing

Comment: I actually get a malformed query with this attempt.

Comment: Would you like to give more information. What wrong response did you get?